# How do I put queried values in an object and return it to another script?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to put the values of multiple queries in an object and return it to my main script to be displayed. My understanding for OOP is not that great, but the response I am getting back from the page seems as though I am putting an object in an object? An explanation of what I'm *really* doing would be appreciated but here is my code:

```
<?php
 require "../../inc/dbinfo.inc";

 $num = $_POST['num'];

 $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS sq FROM tblVendorInvoices WHERE VendorPOID1 = '$num'");
 $res->sq = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);

 $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT POAmount AS poam FROM tblVendorPOs WHERE VENDORPOID = '$num'");
 $res->poam = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);

 echo json_encode($res);
 exit();
?>
```

**Response I get:**

`{"sq":{"sq":"0"},"poam":{"poam":"0.14"}}`

**Expected response (format-wise):**

`{"sq":"0","poam":"0.14"}`

Comment: @JessicaThedoc I get server error 500 when I try this.

Comment: You should not leave thanks comment. See this meta post: [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

You are correct - you **are** putting objects in an object. The response you are getting looks confusing because you have an object property and returned column aliased with the same name.

You have a `$res` object with the property name "sq" (`$res->sq`) and you are setting the column name in your query to "sq" as well (`SELECT COUNT(*) AS sq...`).

#### Solution

To get the response you want, you need only set your object property to the *column value* instead of the whole object `{column_name: value}` for both the `sq` and `poam` queries. For example:

```
$res->sq = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)->sq;

$res->poam = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)->poam;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
//$res->sq = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
$res->sq = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)->sq;
```

and

```
//$res->poam = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
$res->poam = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)->poam;
```